# WebGL texture pixel value modify

Tags: javascript, textures, webgl

I'm trying to modify the pixel value of my texture.
Ex: I want to set the texture more transparent.
I used gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") and gl.readPixels() to get the pixel value of my texture.

The code is as below:

```
  var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, sTexture, 0);

  if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) == gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
  {
      var sTextureSize = sTexture.image.width * sTexture.image.height * 4;    // r, g, b, a
      var pixels = new Uint8Array( sTextureSize );
      gl.readPixels( 0, 0, sTexture.image.width, sTexture.image.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );

      for( var i=0 ; i<sTextureSize ; i+=4 )
      {
          if( pixels[i+3] > 0 )
          {
              pixels[i+3] = Math.min( 255, pixels[i+3]*0.5 );     // set half alpha
          }
      }

  }

  gl.deleteFramebuffer(framebuffer);
```

After doing this process it looked like that the transparency of my texture is not be changed.

I know that I can modify the texture alpha value via shader code, but is it possible to directly edit the texture pixel value and show the effect immediately ?

Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to re-upload the changes with `gl.texImage2D`

```
  var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
  gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
  gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, sTexture, 0);

  if (gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER) == gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
  {
      var sTextureSize = sTexture.image.width * sTexture.image.height * 4;    // r, g, b, a
      var pixels = new Uint8Array( sTextureSize );
      gl.readPixels( 0, 0, sTexture.image.width, sTexture.image.height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels );

      for( var i=0 ; i<sTextureSize ; i+=4 )
      {
          if( pixels[i+3] > 0 )
          {
              pixels[i+3] = Math.min( 255, pixels[i+3]*0.5 );     // set half alpha
          }
      }

      // upload changes
      gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, sTexture);
      gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 
                    sTexture.image.width, sTexture.image.height, 0,
                    gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
  }

  gl.deleteFramebuffer(framebuffer);
```

`gl.readPixels` just reads a copy of the texture. You modify the copy. You then have to upload that copy back to the texture.

NOTE: if you're using mips you'll need to call `gl.generateMipmap` or update the mips manually if want them to take into account your changes.

Comment: Just to be clear, if I want to mutate the values inside a texture, I must call `bindTexture` and `texImage2D`, even if that's every animation frame? I expected to be able to mutate the JS typed-array that holds the underlying data (`pixels` in the example), then call something like `uniform1i` to tell the GPU to recopy the array. Having to repeatedly specify the type, size, internal and external formats etc every time we update a texture just seems redundant and clunky.

Comment: you can use `texSubImage2D` instead of `texImage2D`. In that case you don't specify the internal format. The rest is required (which mip level, the destX, destY, the width and height, the format and type of the source data. If you want something as you suggest then write your own wrapper API. Whether or it's clunky is an opinion. With your design, if I get the data in some other typedarray then I'd have to copy it to the shadow which would be a huge waste of time. With the current API I just pass any typedarray regardless of its source (from a fetch, a websocket, an audio sample, an ImageData

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for explaining. Much appreciated.